Extracting plain text from .properties files that can have html and markdown syntax
I'm currently working on a project where I need to extract translatable plain text from .properties i18n.properties files. Usually whenever I need to protect something from the translator I use regex to get those elements and remove from the file, later adding them back. Issue is that now I have some files that might have markdown or html syntax, which cannot be described using Regex, will post some examples below. Do you know any java libs that could solve this issue, or have any tips on how to cover it?
Examples:
The quick brown fox {0,choice,0# jumps|1#[Jumps]({1})} over the lazy dog

In this example the result I expect would be like
The quick brown fox {0} jumps {1} jumps {2} over the lazy dog
It don't need to have just the 3 placeholder, their could be more, but the result needs to have all the syntax hidden inside placeholder, and all the translatable plain text available for the translator to edit. Other MD and html could appear and they can be combined in any way. Also nested inside each other, like multiple 'choice' nested, bold, lists, links, etc...
I have looked into the standard java libs for localization like okapi, but coulnd't find any way to combine the .properties and the MD syntax.

Translation, regular expressions and specific format parsing are totally different things. Try finding a parser for Markdown and a parser for HTML.
